# Parameter null in C# code but it is set in AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with C#, .NET Framework 4.7 and jQuery 1.11.2.

This javascript code:

```
function RequestCodes(button, poId) {
    var URL = '/ProductionOrder/RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder';
    //button.attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $('#ok').hide();
    $('#fail').hide();
    $('#cargando').show();

    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "HTML",
        data: { productionOrderId: poId },
        contentType: "json",
        success: function () {
            $('#cargando').hide();
            $('#ok').show();

            $("#ok").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $('#ok').hide();
            });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            $('#cargando').hide();
            $('#fail').show();

            $("#fail").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $('#fail').hide();
                //button.removeAttr("disabled");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Throws this error:

> he parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'productionOrderId' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder(Int32)' in
>   'TRZF.Web.API.Controllers.ProductionOrderController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter.Parameter name: parameters.

When I call the method:
`public ActionResult RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder(int productionOrderId)`

The problem is with the parameter name in the javascript code, but I don't know how why because it has the same name like in the C# code.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Show your RouteMap setup please

Comment: please use english names while programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url: URL,
    type: "PUT",
    data: { productionOrderId: poId },
    success: function () {
        $('#cargando').hide();
        $('#ok').show();

        $("#ok").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $('#ok').hide();
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        $('#cargando').hide();
        $('#fail').show();

        $("#fail").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $('#fail').hide();
            //button.removeAttr("disabled");
        });
    }
});
```

I have removed `dataType: "HTML",` and `contentType: "json",`, and now it works.

I have done another test, removing only `contentType: "json",` and it works. So, I think the problem is with setting the `contentType`.

Comment: `contentType` itself determines format of posted data, i.e. `contentType: "json"` will expects JSON data to be posted. The opposite apply for `dataType: "json"`, which expects returned data format in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

you have syntax error at below line. I have fixed this.

```
data: "{'productionOrderId':'" + poId + "'}",
```

Answer (score 0):

at controller **RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder** function you need to get productionOrderId with nullable data type like following :

```
RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder(int? productionOrderId)
{
//your code here
}
```

? mean accept nullable data type

Answer (score 0):

changing the content type to "application/json" and strigifying the data fixed the issue for me.
here is the sample code.

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "/Home/RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: JSON.stringify({

            productionOrderId: 1

      }),
      contentType: "application/json",//change "json" to "application/json" 
       success: function () {
           console.log("success");
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("error");
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, is your route to the api correct? 
Usually it's prefixed with `api/`..

---

Secondly, the client model that you are sending to the server is not matching the expected value type (`int`) on the server side.

**Option 1** is to match the server side with the client side object.

Your client object  `{ productionOrderId: poId }` is equal to a server side model defined as this

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public int productionOrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Use the model in the api controller method and read it from the body

```
public ActionResult RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder([FromBody]RequestModel model){}
```

NOTE: Don't forget to stringify the object before sending it in the client when using content type application/json, `data: JSON.stringify({ productionOrderId: })`

**Option 2** is to send the productionOrderId in the route

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ProductionOrder")]
public class ProductionOrder : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder/{productionOrderId}")]
    public ActionResult RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder(int productionOrderId){}
}
```

Then call this method by using url `api/ProductionOrder/RequestCodeForIncompleteOrder/2345` where 2345 is your order id